# How to stop python newspaper3k from returning null values?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, null

I've been using the python newspaper library recently, and I'm trying to create a system which searches through all of the articles on the BBC News website and inserts each title into a MySQL database located on my PC within a WAMP server. My issue is that the following code returns both actual article titles and null values, which I obviously do not want in my database. Is there any way I can stop this from happening?

Thanks :)

```
import newspaper
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="",
  database="headlines"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "insert into headlines (headline) values (%s)"

search = newspaper.build('https://www.bbc.co.uk/news')

for article in search.articles:

    mycursor.execute(sql, (article.title,))
    mydb.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the null entries in your database appear by `None` entries from Python being uploaded to your MySQL server. If this is the case, you can simply check if the article is `None`, then skipping it from being uploaded to the DB.

```
for article in search.articles:
    if article is None:
        continue
    mycursor.execute(sql, (article.title,))
    mydb.commit()
```